# Como, ao clicar na notificação, excluir a notificação e não abrir o aplicativo?

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Preciso enviar uma notificação mas gostaria que quando o usuário clicar na notificação a mesma seja excluída e não abra o aplicativo

A parte de gerar a notificação isso já esta funcionando o não consegui travar o aplicativo para não ser aberto.

Grato.

Answer (score 3):

Para que a notificação não lançe nenhuma Activity(Intent) ao ser clicada crie o *PendigIntent*, passado ao método `setContentIntent()` do *NotificationCompat.Builder*, da seguinte forma:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  0, new Intent(), 0);
```

Substitua os `0` pelos valores que quiser utilizar. O importante é passar `new Intent()` no terceiro parâmetro.

Para excluir a notificação ao ser clicada use `setAutoCancel(true)` ao construir a notificação.

Answer (score 0):

Crie a notificação:

```
private void sendNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
    builder.setContentTitle("My title");
    builder.setContentText("Content Text");
    Intent removeNotifivationIntent = new Intent();
    removeNotifivationIntent.setAction(REMOVE_NOTIFICATION);
    PendingIntent removeNotifivationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, removeNotifivationIntent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(removeNotifivationPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Crie um BroadcastReceiver,  pode ser no OnCreate:

```
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (REMOVE_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
                nMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```